# What Stat type store in Doors DXL?

Tags: stat, ibm-doors

What is the purpose of the `Stat` type? Something like the status of an operation? I did not find much in the DXL Reference Manual 9.6.

> The functions that use the Stat data type work on the stat API
>   provided by the operating system, which enables DXL programs to
>   determine the status of files and directories

To be more clear I will post one of its usages:

```
/************************************
    isDirectory

    Returns true if string parameter is a valid directory
************************************/
bool isDirectory(string dn)
{
    Stat s = create dn

    if (null s) return false
    if (directory s)
    {
        delete s
        return true
    }
    delete s
    return false
}
```

Or the code like this:

```
/************************************
    getFileSize

    returns the size (in bytes) of a file. note that files smaller than
    the block size on the disc still take up a whole block.
************************************/
int getFileSize(string fn)
{
    int fSize = 0
    Stat s = create fn
    if (null s) return(0)

    fSize = size(s)
    if (fSize < BLOCK_SIZE) fSize = BLOCK_SIZE

    delete s
    return(fSize)
}
```

**Edit**:

*Or Perms like:*

Date modified (Stat)

bool symbolic (Stat)

Date accessed (Stat)

Stat create (Symbolic__)

void delete (Stat)

string user (Stat)

int size (Stat)

Comment: Please be careful not to make new, overly broad tags like `create`. Thank you!

Comment: There are only two questions tagged [doors-9.5], one of them is this, which is really for Doors 9.6. I'll remove the [doors-9.5] tag from this one. If there is any opposition to it, please feel free to restore the tag and I'll not remove it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stat` is a data structure describing files and file-like elements like directories. You already found the purpose of this structure: *to determine the status of files and directories*. As the Reference Manual mentions in section 11, subsection *Operating system commands*, it is just a way to access OS `stat` function and datatype using DXL.

For *nix based systems, the structure is fully described at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html. For Windows based systems, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx. You will notice that the concept is basically identical.

> The `_stat` function obtains information about the file or directory
>   specified by path and stores it in the structure pointed to by buffer. [Windows]
>
> These functions return information about a file. [Linux]

Since handling bit masks is not too handy, it is common practice to have a set of functions like `bool directory (Stat)` to check distinct flags in a more readable manner. If you are not interested in using the stat buffer at all, you usually create a layer of convenience functions on top, like `bool isDirectory(string)` in your example, so that you can check even more readable if a file/directory is a directory, is readable etc.